# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add'  of undefined
```

I want to make a mute bot he simply gives the role. I use Node.js V12.2.0 and try to make a mute bot with the code.

```
//mute
client.on("message", async message => {
  let cmd = message
  if (message.content === 'mutetest') {
    message.author.roles.add(724230067785433099)
  }
})
```

Comment: Author is of type User and does not have a `roles` property. Please read the docs. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User 
What version of Discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `message.member`. This will give you a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object  that has a `roles` property:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  let cmd = message
  if (message.content === 'mutetest') {
    message.member.roles.add(724230067785433099)
  }
})
```